# Creating Laravel Sub-domain

Tags: php, laravel, subdomain

I have a problem creating laravel sub-domain (I'm using Laravel 5.5)

```
Route::group(['domain' => 'profile.website.com'], function() {
    Route::get('profile', ProfileController@getProfiles');
});
```

When I try to reach the profile.website.com/profile website it throws a Could not get any response error

Any thoughts?

Thank for the answers in advance

Comment: Have you pointed the subdomain to the same server?

Comment: you have to configure your apache too

Comment: Is there a guide how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

[Apache Docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html) show how to configure vhosts. Basically a subdomain will be a separate vhost that points to the same DocumentRoot. [Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#route-group-sub-domain-routing) Also give some explanation on using subdomains. Here is a sample vhosts config:

```
# Ensure that Apache listens on port 80
Listen 80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/www/laravel"
    ServerName www.laravelapp.com

    # Other directives here
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/www/laravel"
    ServerName subdomain.laravelapp.com

    # Other directives here
</VirtualHost>
```

As someone already mentioned, you will need to have an A record for your subdomain pointing to your server.

Comment: Thank you, that is what I needed